# Is it feasible to deploy or implement Journey builder custom activity on SFDC(sales cloud or service cloud or force.com) or Marketing cloud itself?

Tags: marketing-cloud, force.com-sites, journeybuilder, custom-activity

Can we achieve it without deploying on external web hosting like gcp,aws or azure? If yes, Could you provide me some sample or guidance?
Thank you in advance.